# Get table cell value on first rowclick in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a value of a cell in a html table within JavaScript. I can do this when the row is clicked twice or when I click on a row and then another row but I need to get the cell value on **first click**

This is my code so far

```
var table = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_htmltable');

if (table != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                cellvalue = this.innerHTML;
            };
    }
}
```

This runs on an `onclick` event on the `ASPxListBox` object from devexpress I am using.

Note: I can't use third party libraries like jQuery for this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about the relevance of the ASPxListBox. I've created a jsfiddle here which shows how to create event listeners on table cells: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcadeGandalf/5xcwwwmn/)

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle code posted by arcade Gandalf above does work, however, to fix my problem of getting the cell value on first click, the code needs to run when the page load is complete

```
window.onload = getCellValueOfTable;

function getCellValueOfTable {
   jsFiddle code or my code posted above...
}
```

Then in the `onclick` event for the listbox or a table as I described in the question, just call the above function and that is all.